# Transition of tabs not working only in safari

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I create intern tabs with js and css, but the transition of tabs it's not working only in safari. In chrome, edge, and opera it's normal. Somebody could help me? please?

```js
function abas() {
    console.log("abas skip");
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
});
}
```

```css
.tabs-container{
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
ul.tabs{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    }
ul.tabs li{
        background: none;;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
ul.tabs li.current{
        border-bottom: 2px solid #F65314;
    }
.tab-content{
        display: none;
        padding: 15px;
    }
.tab-content.current{
        display: inherit;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-container">
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Cases</li>
<li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">E-books</li>
<li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Artigos Cient&iacute;ficos</li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
<ul>
(...)
</ul>
</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
<p>Artigos Cient&iacute;ficos</p>
<ul>
</div>
```

Some things are different of usual because i'm coding in a LMS Canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add below code?

```
$("body")
.addClass("dummyClass")
.removeClass("dummyClass");
```

The problem is that sometime safari doesn't redraw the page when we change CSS so we need to force redrawing

Comment: Is that class add/remove function working as expected?

Comment: Wait.... worked, in safari, but not in chrome kkk but now i can make work. Very thank you <3 <3

Comment: it's very weird, because when i reload the page the first time the code work, but the second time not worked anymore.